# How to convert a three-line Ruby method into one

Tags: ruby, variables, block

I have a simple method that iterates through an array and returns a duplicate. (Or duplicates)

```
def find_dup(array)
  duplicate = 0
  array.each { |element| duplicate = element if array.count(element) > 1}
  duplicate
end
```

It works, but I'd like to express this more elegantly.

The reason it is three lines is that the variable "duplicate", which the method must return, is not visible to the method if I introduce it inside the block, i.e,

```
def find_dup(array)
  array.each { |element| duplicate = element if array.count(element) > 1}
  duplicate
end
```

I've tried a few ways to define "duplicate" as the result of a block, but to no avail.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you trying to find a single duplicate or the last duplicate or an array of duplicates? Also, your current code is iterating through all elements in the array twice in a nested fashion and re-setting duplicate to the last duplicate found.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little too much to do cleanly in a one-liner, but this is a more
efficient solution.

```
def find_dups(arr)
  counts = Hash.new { |hash,key| hash[key] = 0 }
  arr.each_with_object(counts) do |x, memo|
    memo[x] += 1
  end.select { |key,val| val > 1 }.keys
end
```

The `Hash.new` call instantiates a hash where the default value is 0.

`each_with_object` modifies this hash to track the count of each element in `arr`, then at the
end the `filter` is used to select only those having a count greater than one.

The benefit of this approach over a solution using `Array#includes?` or `Array#count` is that it only scans the array a single time. Thus it is a O(N) time instead of O(N^2).

Comment: Thanks, this is a better solution.  The one-liner still eludes me, but, hey, it was worth a shot!

Answer (score 1):

Your method is only finding the last duplicate in the array. If you want all the duplicates, I would do something like this:

```
def find_dups(arr)
  dups = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = 0 }
  arr.each { |el| dups[el] += 1 }
  dups.select { |k, v| v > 1 }.keys
end
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  It doesn't exactly answer my question, bit it's good to know about the code.

Comment: So is the issue that you want the block to be a closure so that `duplicate` is still available after the block runs? Because if so, I think the way you have it is the way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

If what you really want is a one-liner that isn't concerned with big-O complexity and only returns the last duplicate in the array, I would do this:

```
def find_last_dup(arr)
  arr.reverse_each { |el| return el if arr.count(el) > 1 }
end
```

Comment: use `reverse_each` when chaining `reverse` and `each`. Other than that, nice solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as one line and it flows a bit nicer. Though this would find the first instance of a duplicate whereas your code is returning the last instance of a duplicate, not sure if that's part of your requirement.

```
def find_dup(array)
  array.group_by { |value| value }.find { |_, groups| groups.count > 1 }.first
end
```

Also, note that making things one line doesn't strictly mean is better. I'd find the code more readable split over more lines, but that's just my opinion.

```
def find_dup(array)
  array.group_by { |value| 
    value 
  }.find { |_, groups| 
    groups.count > 1 
  }.first
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
> a
=> [8, 5, 6, 6, 5, 8, 6, 1, 9, 7, 2, 10, 7, 7, 3, 4]
```

You can group the dups together:

```
> a.uniq.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) {|e, h| c=a.count(e); h[e]=c if c>1}
=> {8=>2, 5=>2, 6=>3, 7=>3}
```

Or,

```
> a.group_by{ |e| e}.select{|k,v| v if v.length>1}
=> {8=>[8, 8], 5=>[5, 5], 6=>[6, 6, 6], 7=>[7, 7, 7]}
```

In each case, the order of the result is based on the order of the elements in `a` that have dups. If you just want the first:

```
> a.group_by{ |e| e}.select{|k,v| v if v.length>1}.first
=> [8, [8, 8]]
```

Or last:

```
> a.group_by{ |e| e}.select{|k,v| v if v.length>1}.to_a.last
=> [7, [7, 7, 7]]
```

If you want to 'fast forward' to the first value that has a dup, you can use drop_while:

```
> b=[1,2,3,4,5,4,5,6]
> b.drop_while {|e| b.count(e)==1 }[0]
=> 4
```

Or the last:

```
> b.reverse.drop_while {|e| b.count(e)==1 }[0]
=> 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Just want to add one more approach to the mix.

```
def find_last_dup(arr)
  arr.reverse_each.detect { |x| arr.count(x) > 1 }
end
```

Alternatively, you can get linear time complexity in two lines.

```
def find_last_dup(arr)
  freq = arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |x, obj| obj[x] += 1 }
  arr.reverse_each.detect { |x| freq[x] > 1 }
end
```

For the sake of argument, the latter approach can be reduced to one line as well, but this would be unidiomatic and confusing.

```
def find_last_dup(arr)
  arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |x, obj| obj[x] += 1 }
    .tap do |freq| return arr.reverse_each.detect { |x| freq[x] > 1 } end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def find_duplicates(array)
  array.dup.uniq.each { |element| array.delete_at(array.index(element)) }.uniq
end
```

The above method **find_duplicates** duplicated the input array and deletes the first occurrence of all the elements, leaving the array with only remaining occurrences of the duplicate elements.

Example:

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3]
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3] 
find_duplicates(array)
=> [3, 4]
```